# Difference " I grabbed his collar" and " I grabbed him by the collar"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which one is more used in a daily conversation?

To me, "I grabbed his collar" would be more used than " I grabbed him by the collar".

Is there any different shades of meaning?

"I grabbed him by the collar"  seems like "I subdued him in any way by getting hold of his collar" : a police officer catching a criminal by grasping his collar tightly.

Comment: Which is used more in daily conversation? Neither is particularly common in polite society. However, if you wouldn't mind explaining what you're after, we might be of more help. On the face of it, the first is more documentary, while the second is more emotionally charged. However, both sentences admit a wide emotional range, dependent on context.

Comment: [According to ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grabbed+his+collar%2C+grabbed+him+by+the+collar&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrabbed%20his%20collar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrabbed%20him%20by%20the%20collar%3B%2Cc0) the second is about twice as popular. Of course, that ngram has about as much content as your question. You chose the tag [tag:meaning-in-context] yet you provided almost none. Please consider enhancing your question with more context.

Comment: "Grabbed him by the collar" is often used in a figurative sense.  "Grabbed his collar", not so much.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret "I grabbed his collar" literally, and with the intent of describing that you did so by grabbing a piece of his attire.

However, "I grabbed him by the collar" is different in two ways:

- The emphasis is on the fact you grabbed him.
- The collar is a metaphor for the fact you did so to control his actions. Think less like a part of a shirt and more like the thing you attach a leash to.

---

e.g. your girlfriend might grab your collar to get your attention, but she'd grab you by the collar to pull you into a passionate kiss.

Answer (score -1):

I would always say "I grabbed him by the collar."  It's just more satisfying that way.

Please note that you can use this phrase emphatically even if you haven't literally grabbed someone by the collar.  For example, I might march my child over to a mess he had promised to clean up, and describe it later to someone else in my family: "I grabbed him by the collar and showed him the mess that was still there."

Comment: Presumably if he wasn't wearing his collar when you grabbed it you wouldn't say "I grabbed him by the collar".